# Como fazer sequência em R?

Tags: r

Preciso fazer esta sequencia em uma estrutura de repetição para usar com um N maior, mas não estou conseguindo fazê-lo, alguém tem alguma ideia de como fazer isto?

```
n=8
names <- c (seq(1 , n), seq(2,n+1 ), seq (3,n+2), seq(4 ,n+3), seq(5,n+5 ),seq(6,n+5),seq(7, n+6 ), seq (8,n+7))
```

Obrigado desde já..

Comment: Acho que seu código está errado, não seria `seq(5,n+4)`? Faz mais sentido pela lógica das outras sequencias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se o que você quer é uma maneira de fazer a sequência mais dinâmica, pode usar o seguinte:

```
n=8
names <- rep(1:n, n)+rep(0:(n-1), each=n)
#[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  3  4  5  6  7  8
#[23]  9 10  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12  6  7  8  9
#[45] 10 11 12 13  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

Dessa forma você cria a sequencia `1:n` `n` vezes, e adiciona `0, 1, 2...n-1` a cada `1:n`.

Comment: Era isso mesmo que eu estava buscando, muito obrigado :)

Answer (score 1):

Complementando com mais uma opção de resposta, você também pode usar `lapply`.

```
criar_seq <- function(x){
    seq(x, (n+x-1))
}

n <- 8
lapply(1:n, criar_seq)
```

Isso retornará uma lista de **n** sequências com a progressão de mais um. Se você quiser colocar os dados como vetor, é só aplicar `unlist`.